# Public entity properties in zend 2 documentation - is it good?

Tags: oop, zend-framework2

I was writing app with zend 2 framework. I had not worked with it, some time ago done small app maybe with zend 1.

I see what is not usual to me - public properties. I thought this is bad. But zend is showing such examples:

```
namespace Album\Model;

 class Album
 {
     public $id;
     public $artist;
     public $title;

     public function exchangeArray($data)
     {
         $this->id     = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
         $this->artist = (!empty($data['artist'])) ? $data['artist'] : null;
         $this->title  = (!empty($data['title'])) ? $data['title'] : null;
     }
 }
```

https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

Is is good for this case? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of those examples, zend tends to simplify their code, but when you develop your app, your must use your best practises you've learned. So if you think those properties deserve to be at least protected, so be it, it's good and I agree with you.

Sometimes zend, when they explain some stuff and uses the ServiceLocator they use it in controllers, it's not a good practise at all, because the serviceLocator is not mean to be used that way, plus, it was removed from controllers in zf3. Again they do it for explain some concept, and for the sake of tutorials they gave some bad code. The community suffered of this.

I advise you to be suspicious, more, skeptic about what Zend give into their tutorials, they just explain the functionnality but you shall not just blind copy what they provide. Only understand what they mean.